# SkyScanner forage project

Tags: download, project, npx

When I am copying the following code in my terminal I am unable to download the project file.

`npx create-react-app@3.4.1 my-app --scripts-version=@skyscanner/backpack-react-scripts --template @skyscanner/backpack --use-npm`

Any suggestions for this on how to download it?

I tried the copying the code and pasting it in vs code terminal but it is showing error while downloading the file